# ssh ProxyCommand fails: "forbidden char/command over SSH"

Tags: ssh, paramiko

I am trying to `ssh` over my university's proxy server, to one of our lab's servers. The goal is to automate it with paramiko, but I am trying to first understand what's happening in the terminal level.

I tried

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh eran@proxy_server nc inner_server 22' eran@inner_server
```

And got

```
*** forbidden char/command over SSH: "nc inner_server 22"
This incident has been reported.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Which I guess means the server does not allow the `ProxyCommand`.

Any way to achieve this in a different way? 
Just to be clear, `ssh` to proxy_server, and then to inner_server, works fine, but doesn't produce a paramiko SSHClient instance, which is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: It seems the SSH gateway doesn't allow you to run arbitrary commands as `nc`. You should investigate which commands are allowed.

Comment: True. I guess I thought nc is the only way to use the ProxyCommand, thus I concluded that the server does not allow the ProxyCommand. Am I mistaken?

Comment: No, there are other ways, as using the`-W` flag, as explained by @Jakuje bellow (requieres port forwarding enabled which is unlikely), or calling `ssh sshd -i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use netcat. It is probably not allowed on the proxy server. Use -W switch:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p eran@proxy_server' eran@inner_server
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!